# Field _id missing in toObject.transform in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using `schema.toObject.transform` in `mongoose`.

My schema is really simple

```
const nodeSchema = new Schema({
}, {
  toObject: {
    transform: function (doc, ret) {
      return {
        myId: ret._id,
      };
    }
  }
});

const Node = mongoose.model('Node', nodeSchema);
```

I push this `schema` to a parent model with schema

```
const graphSchema = new Schema({
  nodes: [nodeSchema]
});
```

using the `mongoose` syntax

```
const node = new Node({});

Graph.findByIdAndUpdate(graphId, {
  $addToSet: {
    nodes: node
  }
}, (err, graph) => {
  console.log(node.toObject());
});
```

When I do this, the object is transformed correctly with the autogenerated id because I refer directly to `const node = new Node({})`.

The problem is when I try to retrieve all my nodes with

```
Graph.findById(graphId, (err, graph) => {
  console.log(graph.nodes.map(node => node.toObject()));
});
```

Now I won't get the autogenerated id.

I am doing the exact same by calling `node.toObject()`, but it seems the autogenerated id in `_id` is removed from the `Node` object when I use `$addToSet`.

I have also tried `doc._id` instead of `ret._id` in the transform function, but it doesn't change anything.

What I am guessing could be wrong is that I might have misunderstood what `toObject()` does. Will it be called automatically every time I run it through an array?

I just want to store my values in my collection in one way (specific structure) but show it in another way (another, different structure). So I thought I could use `transform` to choose in what structure I want to print it.

Comment: When you `console.log(node.toObject());` you're referring to an object that hasn't yet hit the Mongo db; are you sure this is what you intend to prove here?

Comment: Yes. Because from calling `new Node()`, it has already created an id, so the object is the same as the object created in the database.

Comment: For clarity, it might be useful to separate logging the node from the graph callback and post the outputs of both `node.toObject()`s.